# jQueryUI autocomplete not working in Twitter-Bbootstrap modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete, modal-dialog

I have a php function that creates various autocomplete boxes for use round my pages:

```
$partnerbox= AutoComplete($array,'ps'/*form field name*/,0);
```

I use the form field name inside the jQuery to create individual jQuery functions in case I have multiple boxes to avoid duplicate function names.

It works fine when I output the boxes straight in the page, but when I try load one box inside a twitter modal nada - any ideas?

The input box shows but nothing happens when I type - even if I load just a single working autocomplete box into the modal it stops -

Any ideas?

```
<div class="modal-body">        
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <form role="form">
              <div class="form-group">
               '.$partnerbox2.'
                <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Select client" required> -->
              </div>

              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Submit</button>
            </form>
          </div>          
          <div class="col-md-6">
              <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                  <a href="dashboard.php?vrfq" class="light">View Sent RFQ\'s</a>
              </button>
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: have u checked your error console .. ?

Comment: in firebug i reload the script option, and under console-errors theres nothing..